# Chrome stuck at loading upwork.com

Tags: stock-android, chrome-for-android, google, nexus-6p

When I go to upwork.com the page loads. However, when I click the login button it gets stuck loading.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbUeB.jpg

Comment: What's your question? TBH this sounds like a bug in the website you should raise with the website owner.

Comment: @DanHulme you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the cache and app data. Go to settings --> app manager and find google chrome. Then force stop google chrome and try again.

Try installing Google Chrome Beta (Could be a bug in the current version)

As @TamoghnaChowdhury said, it could also be a website or internet problem if it doesn't load on other phones.

Comment: I cleared chrome and app data, problem still persist.

Comment: It worked when I installed Google chrome beta on my android, thank you a asloss.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I'll edit my answer to account for that!

Answer (score 0):

Do other websites load normally? I guess they do. Hence, this is a probably a problem with the website, not with Chrome or Android. Be patient and try again later.

Re: About it working with Chrome Beta, it could be any number of other factors related to the website other than Chrome.

Comment: it could easily be a bad plugin from that chrome version. but yes i would agree about it potentially being a website error.  he should have seen if it loaded on other devices at the time.  No worries though because it is working now :)

Comment: @asloss, You should know that Chrome on Android doesn't support plugins, and had never done so, so that is a moot point. Also, he most probably didn't bother to check the website on any other device, so I would say he got lucky.

Comment: Not what I meant by plugin (Although plugin is the wrong word I will admit), but yah sorry about not referencing you, I just figured since the answer was already marked I would put it in there for future readers. Didn't know how to cite, whoops